# How to divide one array into two half arrays in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, loops

I have one array. I need to divide that array into two halves; first half in one array, second in another.

**tried code:**

```
let totalArray = [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]

var firstArray = [Int]()
var secondArray = [Int]()

for i in totalArray.indices {
    if i <= totalArray.count/2 {
        firstArray.append(contentsOf: [i])
    } else {
        secondArray.append(contentsOf: [i])
    }
}
```

o/p:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
> [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

But I need it like this:

> firstArray = [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15]
> secondArray = [14, 13, 12, 11, 10]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `firstArray.append(totalArray[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contentsOf` gives you the content of "i" itself, which carries the index number (the position of the array item), not the respective value of the array item.

You want:

```
firstArray.append(totalArray[i])

secondArray.append(totalArray[i])
```

That way, you get back the value from the array item at the respective position.

Answer (score 3):

You are appending the indices rather than the values (see howaldoliverdev's answer).

But this is Swift. There are more convenient ways to split the array for example

```
let totalArray = [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10]

let mid = (totalArray.count + 1) / 2

let firstArray = Array(totalArray[..<mid])
let secondArray = Array(totalArray[mid...])
```

Comment: I am on my mobile but OP it is using <= not <